# What User-Agent to give my WebApi Requests?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, user-agent, fiddler, restsharp

I am using an api and I noticed that when I use `RestSharp` and do a call from my `asp.net web api project` my request fails.

I turned on `fiddler` and for whatever reason the api I am requesting thinks I am a mobile device and thus is redirecting me to the mobile site that does not support api calls.

I then did a request in `fiddler` and I can access the api. I changed my `user-agent` to `fiddler` through `restsharp` and now my requests go through when using my `web api`.

I don't want to leave it `fiddler` though. What should I use instead?

Comment: http://youruseragent.info/commonua.en.htm has a list of common user agents - you could try picking one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in-effect creating your own user-agent, so invent your own identifier.  E.g. choboAgent/1.0